# Is homotopy a consequence of making paths composable and invertible?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, education, fundamental-groups

Many introductions to algebraic topology go like this:

1. We want to study spaces by studying paths in them.
2. It is intuitive that one wants to compose paths, but the naive way to compose them fails horribly.
3. this is fixed by considering paths up to homotopy
4. the notion of homotopy can be defined for arbitrary maps, not only paths, so lets do homotopy theory…

From a applied perspective this is of cause perfectly fine. But it was (and still is) unclear to me exactly *why* we use homotopies and not some other tool to fix the composability issue of paths.

There are some obvious „fixes“, which are sometimes discussed:

- one could try to simply use the images of the paths. Thinking of loops this is of cause not a great idea, because we cannot distinguish the number of times the loop winds around a hole. So we drop this approach.
- another idea is to use intervals of different lengths. This gives a strict category of paths in a space $X$, but it is not a groupoid. We would like paths to be invertible, so we have to fix this somehow. This leads us to reparametrizations, but then the whole „different lengths“ business isn’t really necessary anymore.

So we agree that we somehow want to define a groupoid of paths in $X$ and we need to impose an equivalence relation on them to make this happen. From an algebraic perspective the usual way to solve this problem would then be to use the equivalence relation $\sim$ generated by our necessities (composability, const paths are identities, invertibility, stability under reparametrization…).

Without thinking about this too much I always thought this would be the equivalence relation given by homotopy, until I recently read in [this lovely little blogpost](https://www.matem.unam.mx/%7Eomar/groupoids/day2.html) that this is **not** the case. But then

> Why is the answer to defining the fundamental groupoid „consider paths up to paths“ and not „consider paths up to canonical requirements“?

Disclaimer: this is a purely pedagogical question, I am **not** questioning the use of homotopy. But I feel like even if we introduce homotopies before trying to compose paths (ie. if we don’t use paths as motivation for homotopies, but vice versa) it would be a lie to just say „we don’t have to worry about composability, because we already know about homotopies“, if there is another obvious solution…

As always: thank you very much for your time!

> **TLDR** I think it is a quite canonical idea to compose paths. Can this be a hook for developing the notion of homotopy? Does the desire to compose and invert paths naturally lead to considering paths of paths ie. homotopies?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point. Homotopies were being studied way before fundamental group was introduced. In fact homology was invented first. Homotopy theory is much broader, and it does not boil down to path composition. Homologies for example do perfectly well without it.

Comment: Maybe it is just how I was introduced to homotopy theory, namely „we want fundamental groups, hence we need homotopies“. My point is that I don’t understand this „hence“. As I said this question is not about why homotopies provide a solution to the problem of composing paths, but why they are treated as if they were the canonical way to solve it.

Comment: I also don’t know why we would expect singular / simplicial homology to be homotopy invariant, so I don’t really understand how people would go from „we want homology“ to „we need homotopy“. But this is a question for another time, on which I’d rather not dwell here.

Comment: That sentence „we want fundamental groups, hence we need homotopies“ doesn't make much sense, since we can't even define fundamental group without homotopy. Its like saying "we want bread, hence we need flour", but you can't even know what bread is without flour, so how can you want it a priori? No, homotopy was first, then fundamental/homology groups were invented. And all of that was in order to solve a concrete problem: how to formally, mathematically describe what a hole is.

Comment: I think you have also experienced a lecture in the "we will need the following definition / fact" style, so you understand that "we want fundamental groups so we need homotopy" can happen. I think this is weak didactics as well, but here we are. But I think it is a quite canonical idea to compose paths and my question is: Can this be a hook for developing the notion of homotopy? Does the desire to compose and invert paths naturally lead to considering paths of paths ie. homotopies?

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing the style of "introduction to algebraic topology".  In particular, I would say the point of homotopies in the context of studying paths is not to make composition associative, but to give a small invariant that you have any hope of ever computing in a useful sense.  The set of all paths is intractibly huge so you want to impose an equivalence relation that reduces it to something much smaller and classifiable but which still captures some geometric information.  The fact that it happens to also give you a groupoid is something of a happy accident.

Comment: I would also mention that the notion of homotopy of paths arises very naturally as a useful tool in separate contexts.  For instance, you can be interested in covering spaces without ever knowing anything about paths or homotopies, and then homotopy classes of loops turn out to be exactly what you need to understand all the covering spaces of a space "intrinsically" to the space.  Or, in complex analysis, homotopies arise naturally as a way to change a path you're integrating along without changing the integral of a holomorphic function.